# Simplest/best way to make an existing ASP.NET/jQuery site show more suitable UI on smartphones

Tags: jquery, iphone, asp.net, android, smartphone

I have some existing (largish) ASP.NET web applications that people are starting to visit using smartphones.

I'm looking at ways to detect what kind of device they're on and make simple changes to the UI, something like:

*Oh! You're an iPhone! Alright, let's just shrink the page's header - title and logos and stuff - and increase the font and button sizes a bit.*

I've been looking at using either ASP.NET or jQuery to detect what kind of device they're browsing with, then change styles client-side (using a few jQuery statements, or by adding an additional .css file, or changing stuff on the master page if I really have to).

Problems:

1. **How to detect?** I thought this was easy: browser window resolution. But it's not that simple: newer smartphones now have some pretty hi-res screens, and netbooks have some pretty low-res ones. So if I just said "1024x768 or lower = smartphone", that would incorrectly identify 7" Netbooks at 800x480 (which could easily handle the normal, non-mobile version of my site). This will only get worse in future as a larger portion or smartphones catch up to typical low-end laptop resolutions. There's no way to (reliably!) tell the *physical* screen size (in cm or inches) is there?
2. **How to implement?** Can I apply a whole stylesheet file with jQuery? has anyone done this? I can do it server-side, but does this limit my detection options?

(If this exact question has been asked before, please let me know, couldn't find anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to Detect:**

This site seems to have a comprehensive detection scheme: 
http://detectmobilebrowser.com/

**How to implement:**

*(Doesn't actually fit OP's situation, only suitable for very large companies or those offering very limited mobile access).*

I think the general practice is to have two separate versions of your website, one that works well for desktops and one that works well for smaller devices.  When they load your website you check their user agent and if it is a mobile device you redirect to your mobile version.

Some examples of how people layout mobile versions:

- http://www.amazon.com/mobile
- http://www.google.com/m
- http://mobile.twitter.com//
- http://m.cnn.com/

Comment: Thanks. This idea worked OK when the best phones had tiny 1"-2" screens. But it's been years since that's been true - will anyone be using such a phone to surf the web going forward, now that Android handsets cost as little as $50? My users won't. Plus, it's **a few dozen weeks of work when I could get 99% of the way there with a few style tweaks**. My whole site will be useable too, not just the key features.

Comment: Despite how high the resolution gets, the devices are still going to fit in your hand and the human eye is only going to be able to see so much comfortably. iPhone 4's offer a resolution so high most people cannot distinguish one pixel from another, a mobile layout is still very necessary.

As for how you design your mobile version, you can put as little or as much effort as you like.  It could be simply a different master page with some style tweaks, or as complex as a ground-up redesign.  You don't have to redesign the entire website and either way you can have a feature complete website.

Comment: I should also mention, the sites listed in the answer are intended for smartphones, not 1"-2" screen phones.  If you goto amazon, google, twitter, or cnn on an android or iOS phone you will be redirected to those sites or some mobile variant.

Comment: Yes, I actually explained in the question, about why you can't use screen resolution to detect mobiles because of high res smartphones with small screens. The code from detectmobilebrowser.com, while obviously a very inelegant solution (it just uses a massive regex to find out of the user agent has "android", "iphone" or any of a hundred others in it - it'll need to be updated every time a new type of mobile device comes out!!!) looks like the best option so far. So I'll wait a bit, and if no better options appear, I'll accept this answer. Thanks again.